# VirtualHosts in MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp

(I've read many StackOverflow articles that address vhosts in MAMP, but none of them solved this.)

I'm trying to set up a virtual host on my MacBook. I'm using the exact same virtual host setup as I am on my Windows machine, which works fine.

First I edited the hosts file. Under the `127.0.0.1 localhost` line I added:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.mysite.com
```

Next I edited /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf and removed the `#` from the vhosts include:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Next I edited /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/Gavin/Web"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/Gavin/Web/mysite/public_html"
   ServerName dev.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Next I opened Terminal and ran `dscacheutil -flushcache` and restarted MAMP. `localhost` works fine, `dev.mysite.com` gives the standard Chrome `This webpage is not available` error.

Comment: So what to the http servers log files say?

Comment: No errors in the log. Also when I run `httpd -S` it says my virtual host syntax is OK.

Comment: So if neither the server, nor the client side reports any problems ('I somehow doubt that...), and if also a manual host resolution request fails (`host dev.mysite.com`), then only the gap between is left. So start digging there then: take a network sniffer or a debugging proxy and check the traffic sent (if any). There must be some trace somewhere.

Comment: do you type the URL with http:// ?

Answer (score 2):

You must also define `<Directory>` in vhosts for it to work properly. I believe `localhost` works only because you have it defined in main apache configuration.

You should disable main localhost server in main config, and have this in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
## localhost                                                                 
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                
    DocumentRoot /Users/Gavin/Web                                           
    ServerName localhost                                                       
    ServerAlias www.localhost                                                  

    <Directory "/Users/Gavin/Web">                                          
        Allow from All                                                                  
        AllowOverride all                                                               
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks                                                
    </Directory>                                                                      

    UseCanonicalName on                                                               
</VirtualHost> 

## dev.mysite.com                                                                 
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                
    DocumentRoot /Users/Gavin/Web/mysite/public_html                                           
    ServerName dev.mysite.com                                                       
    ServerAlias www.dev.mysite.com                                                  

    <Directory "/Users/Gavin/Web/mysite/public_html">                                          
        Allow from All                                                                  
        AllowOverride all                                                               
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks                                                
    </Directory>                                                                      

    UseCanonicalName on                                                               
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, to make sure that chrome is really picking up `/etc/hosts` file, type your URLs with `http://` in the address-bar like this:

`http://localhost`
`http://dev.mysite.com`

It is not a good idea to have `.com` for local, so do not use that. Use `.localhost` TLD instead to avoid further problems. `.local` won't work well on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you explain what you mean by `You should disable main localhost server in main config`?

Comment: Main configuration file is `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`. It will has main `localhost` server defined.

Comment: This is the only instance of `localhost` in `httpd.conf`... `ServerName localhost:80`

Comment: I commented that out but still not working. Hmm. Really not sure where to go from here...